# SQLAlchemy: filtering on values stored in nested list of the JSONB field

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Lets say I have a model named `Item`, which contains a JSONB field `data`. One of the records has the following JSON object stored there:

```
{
    "name": "hello",
    "nested_object": {
        "nested_name": "nested"
    },
    "nested_list": [
        {
            "nested_key": "one"
        },
        {
            "nested_key": "two"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can find this record by filtering on the `name` field as such:

```
Session().query(Item).filter(Item.data["name"] == "hello")
```

I can find this record by filtering on the nested object likewise as such:

```
Session().query(Item).filter(Item.data[("nested_object","nested_name")] == "hello")
```

However I am struggling to find a way to find this record by filtering on the value of the item stored within the nested list.
In other words I want to find the record above if the user has provided value "one", and I know to look for it in the key `nested_key` within the `nested_list`.

Is it possible to achieve this with SQLAlchemy filters available?

Answer (score 11):

SQLAlchemy's [`JSONB`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB) type has the [`contains()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator.contains) method for the `@>` operator in Postgresql. [The `@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) is used to check if the left value contains the right JSON path/value entries at the top level. In your case

```
data @> '{"nested_list": [{"nested_key": "one"}]}'::jsonb
```

Or in python

```
the_value = 'one'

Session().query(Item).filter(Item.data.contains(
    {'nested_list': [{'nested_key': the_value}]}
))
```

The method converts your python structure to suitable JSON string for the database.

In Postgresql 12 you can use the [JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) functions:

```
import json

Session().query(Item).\
    filter(func.jsonb_path_exists(
        Item.data,
        '$.nested_list[*].nested_key ? (@ == $val)',
        json.dumps({"val": the_value})))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have got an error message while passing a dictionary to the "contains" function that went as: "psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'". I tried getting contains function to work with other variations on syntax, but to no avail.

Comment: What is your SQLAlchemy version?

Comment: Also, did you try `Item.data[("nested_object","nested_name")].contains(...)` or such instead of `Item.data.contains(...)`? Item access on a `JSONB` column returns a `JSONElement` object, which lacks the comparator methods. You should also include the model class definition in your question, just to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: Where does `func` come from? It throws error for me.

Comment: `from sqlalchemy import func`, at least before SQLA2.