# Using Postgres @> Operator and json_build_object in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query using several Postgres-specific operations:

```
SELECT 
    a.row_id, 
    a.name
FROM
    a 
JOIN
    b
ON
    b.json_record @> json_build_object('path', json_build_object('to', a.name))::jsonb
```

My understanding is that the `@>` operator acts as a comparison, but the comparison methods for `JSONB` in the SQLAlchemy docs reference only **keys**, not **values**.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator

I'm not clear on how I could design this query through SQLAlchemy short of using a raw query.

### Edit 1

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39467149/1886901), I gave the below a try.

```
session \
   .query(A_Table) \
   .join(
      B_Table.json_record.contains({
         'path': {
            'to': A_Table.name
         }
      })
   )
```

It, however, resulted in an error from the line `'to': A_Table.name`:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'selectable'
sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2206, in join
from_joinpoint=from_joinpoint,
File "<string>", line 2, in _join
```

So I instead attempted

```
session \
   .query(A_Table) \
   .filter(
      B_Table.json_record.contains({
         'path': {
            'to': A_Table.name
         }
      })
   )
```

Which at least resulted in a different error, this one with some SQL generation from SQLAlchemy:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) 
Object of type 'InstrumentedAttribute' is not JSON serializable 
[SQL: 'SELECT a.row_id AS a_id, a.name AS a_name FROM a, b 
WHERE b.json_record @> %(json_record_1)s'] [parameters: [{}]]
```

This SQL is close to what I was aiming for, and may be acceptable, but the example provided in the answer presumes I know the value ahead of time, when what I want to do is a comparison against the row value. I typically would do:

```
.filter([a.name == b.json_record['path']['to'].astext])
```

But I'm also trying to leverage an optimization from a `gin` index on this `JSONB` column, which leaves me needing the `@>` operator.

### Edit 2

Based on the answer from Ilja Everilä, I was able to track down the SQLAlchemy method [implemented in the source code](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/database.html#json_sql), and [using the `sql-json` method](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database_helpers.html#json-sql) was able to get the SQL almost there.

```
session \
   .query(A_Table) \
   .join(
      B_Table.json_record.contains({
         json_sql({'path': json_sql({
            'to': A_Table.name
         }
      })
   )
```

Giving me the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    a.row_id, 
    a.name
FROM
    a 
JOIN
    b
ON
    b.json_record @> json_build_object('path', json_build_object('to', a.name))
```

The problem with this output is that instead of:

```
json_build_object(..., json_build_object(...))
```

Valid Postgres syntax should be:

```
json_build_object(..., json_build_object(...))::jsonb
```

Both the answer's and the source code's approach [relies on the `_FunctionGenerator`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=_functiongenerator), which can build the function, but it's not clear how something can get appended to the end of the method during the `compile` when going that route.

### Edit 3

NVM - the answer's author pointed out `jsonb_build_object(...)` would fit with this model w/o the flag.

Comment: Related, somewhat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460387/sqlalchemy-filtering-on-values-stored-in-nested-list-of-the-jsonb-field. Operator `@>` is `contains()` in SQLAlchemy for JSONB columns. Are you using the ORM or Core?

Comment: @IljaEverilä - gave it a go. Looks close, but I need to be able to do column value comparisons, not pass in a value from memory/code. Any ideas? Using ORM.

Comment: An aside: the `<expr>::jsonb` is Postgresql specific syntax for a type cast, not a flag (unless I misinterpret the use of the word here). You could replace it with the SQL standard `CAST(<expr> AS jsonb)`. SQLAlchemy has multiple ways to produce a cast expression, for example the `cast()` construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked Q/A handles the case of using literal values, as you've noticed. The solution is to combine using `contains()` in SQLA and `jsonb_build_object()` in Postgresql as you were trying before:

```
session.query(A_Table) \
    .filter(
        B_Table.json_record.contains(
            func.jsonb_build_object( 
                'path',
                func.jsonb_build_object('to', A_Table.name)
            )
        )
    )
```

> My understanding is that the `@>` operator acts as a comparison, but the comparison methods for `JSONB` in the SQLAlchemy docs reference only keys, not values.

The SQLAlchemy documentation for [`JSONB.Comparator.contains()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator.contains) seems to be a bit poorly written. Compare

> Boolean expression. Test if keys (or array) are a superset of/contained the keys of the argument jsonb expression.

to Postgresql documentation for `@>`:

> Does the left JSON value contain the right JSON path/value entries at the top level?

---

You could hide the details of building `jsonb` in a helper function:

```
def build_jsonb(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        pairs = [(k, build_jsonb(v)) for k, v in obj.items()]
        return func.jsonb_build_object(*[arg for p in pairs for arg in p])

    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return func.jsonb_build_array(*[build_jsonb(v) for v in obj])

    else:
        return obj
```

and then use it in the original query:

```
session.query(A_Table) \
    .filter(
        B_Table.json_record.contains(
            build_jsonb({'path': {'to': A_Table.name}})))
```

If you wish to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
session.query(A_Table).\
    join(B_Table, B_Table.json_record.contains(
        build_jsonb({'path': {'to': A_Table.name}})))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! See my second edit - there is a similar built in method in `sqlalchemy-utils`, but neither method appends `::jsonb` to the `json_build_object`

Comment: There's no need for the cast, if you just use `jsonb_build_object`, as `build_jsonb` does. If you must use the sqlalchemy-utils version, add the cast explicitly: `json_sql(...).cast(JSONB)`.

Comment: Ah - I missed the diff btwn `jsonb_build_object` vs `json_build_object` there - excellent!